# How can you access the edit_XYZ_path for a model when you don't know what type of model it is?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Suppose you have an application that has the following models:  Book, Author, Publisher.  In your routes.rb you have the standard:

```
resources :books
resources :authors
resources :publishers
```

At some point in your code you have a `resource` variable which is either a Book, Author, or Publisher, but you don't know which.

I know I can access the class, by doing `resource.class`, but what's the simplest way to get the edit path (e.g. edit_book_path or edit_author_path)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you only want the path in order to use it with `link_to` so:

`link_to 'Edit', [:edit, resource]`

Comment: Awesome, thanks! In my particular application, the :edit route actually has an extra parameter (step), e.g. `get 'edit(/:step)' => 'book#edit', :on => :member, :as => :edit`.  Do you know how to work that into this syntax?

Comment: You have to use a longer syntax for that: `link_to 'Edit', polymorphic_path(resource, :action => :edit, :step => 1)`.